# apply the style of hover primefaces button when it is clicked jquery

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, primefaces, firebug

I want to apply the hover style of one primefaces button when it is clicked by jquery

with firebug of chrome I noticed that the hover class is `ui-state-hover` but when I searched the code of this style I found only that

```
$("#prix").live('click', function(){
            $(this).css('border-color:inherit;font-weight:inherit;');
        });
```

but it doesn't work

how can I apply the style of hover when the button is clicked

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new class on click using jquery. then you can add any style you want to the new class.

jquery:

```
$("#prix").on('click', function(){
  $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

CSS:

```
.selected{color:#fff}
```

[Jquery addclass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [jquery removeclass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)